# jQuery show car_orig if $(this).attr(.class)=="car"

Tags: jquery, replace, compare

I have `li.box`, `li.car` which are inside a `$(this)` which contain modified values and then I have `box_orig`, `car_orig` containing the original lists...

how can I replace `$(this)`'s data (html data, the li's content) with the original list, so if `$(this)` contains `li.box` then I need to replace it with `box_orig`'s data

Edit:

```
var list              =   $("ul#list");

var box_orig    = list.children('.box');
var car_orig    = list.children('.car');
```

And `$(this)`

```
 $('#list li').each(function () {
     if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'), show) == 0) {
         console.log($(this)); //-> Returns li.box / car or whatever list was selected
     }
 });
```

Re-edit:
***Re-Re-edit:***

I realized that replacing the data breaks anything, so replacing goes out of the question, just show car/box_orig instead li.car/box

```
                $('#list li').each(
                function(){
                    //alert($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) );
                    if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) == 0)
                    {
                        if($(this).attr('class') == 'box')
                        {
                             --> show box_orig, which contains lis with info BUT DO NOT REPLACE THE DATA, just show the box_orig instead of $(this) = li.box
                        }
                        if($(this).attr('class') == 'car')
                        {
                             --> show car_orig, which contains lis with info BUT DO NOT REPLACE THE DATA, just show the box_orig instead of $(this) = li.car
                        }
                        console.log($(this));
                    }
```

html:

```
jQuery(li.car)  result...rifting (line 703)
jQuery(li.car)  result...rifting (line 703)
jQuery(li.car)  result...rifting (line 703)
jQuery(li.car)  result...rifting (line 703)
jQuery(li.car)  result...rifting (line 703)
jQuery(li.car)  result...rifting (line 703)
jQuery(li.car)  result...rifting (line 703)
jQuery(li.car)  result...rifting (line 703)
```

and each li.car contains data (img and text)

Comment: Can you paste some code?

Comment: This question isn't remotely answerable, certainly not definitively, without seeing both your html mark-up *and* your current JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: i just edit the post and added some code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
var list              =   $("ul#list");

var box_orig    = list.children('.box');
var car_orig    = list.children('.car');

...
$('#list li').each(
    function(){
        //alert($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) );
        if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) == 0)
        {
            if($(this).attr('class') == 'box')
            {
                list.append(box_orig);
            }
            if($(this).attr('class') == 'car')
            {
                list.append(car_orig);
            }
        }
        ...
```

Comment: it is not a replacement - you just append to the end of the list original list. Moreover, you append it as many times as you have li with .box or .car, creating doubles.

Comment: for some reason, it doesn't create doubles as you say... it just replaces modified with the original...

Comment: probably because you have only one li element with .box and only one li with .car. Try couple of them. That is why I asked you for the html code and to explain carefully what do you mean by the changes of list.

Comment: javascript is my weakest point in web development... so many times it's even hard to explain my point. I am sorry if I produced you some headaches :D

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you're asking. Do you want to replace the entire object in this class each list item? Or just simply its html content?

If you just want to replace it's content you could do something like this:

```
// Create the list item array + count vars
var list_orig = [];
var list1_count, list2_count = 0;

// Loop through the list items and sort html into the right arrays
// eg. list_orig[0] = [listItem class, listItem id, listItem html content];
$('#list li').each(function(index){

    if($(this).hasClass("list1")){
        list1_count++;
        var id = "list1_" + list1_count;
        $(this).attr("id", id);
        list_orig.push(["list1", id, $(this).html()]);
    }else if($(this).hasClass("list2")){
        list2_count++;
        var id = "list2_" + list2_count;
        $(this).attr("id", id);
        list_orig.push(["list2", id, $(this).html()]);
    }
});
```

This example simply adds an ID to the list item and places this, the class and the original html from each list item into an array "list_orig".

To access the data and revert for example list1 items back to their original content you could do something like this:

```
// Example click function to revert list1 back to it's original html
$("body").click(function(){
    for(var i in list_orig){
        alert(list_orig[i][2]);
        if(list_orig[i][0] == "list1"){
            var id = "#" + list_orig[i][1];
            $(id).html(list_orig[i][2]);
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** Ok so you're wanting to replace the data with the original list data. Here's an example using the new code from your edit:

```
if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) === 0)
{
   // CREATE A TEMPORARY VAR FOR YOUR MATCHED LIST (eg. li.box)
   var x_orig = $(this).attr('class') + "_orig";
   x_orig = window[x_orig]; //USE THIS TO CONVERT THE STRING TO A VARIABLE NAME

   // CREATE A TEMPORRAY VAR FOR THE NEW CONTENT
   var content = x_orig[0]->innerHtml;

   // REPLACE THE CONTENT
   $(this).html(content);
}
```

All I can do without seeing more of your html.

**FURTHER EDIT:** You can actually just use one function without the extra if statements to check for the class. Here we hide the current list, take it's class and construct the class or id of the original list and show that original list.

```
if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) == 0)
{
    // FIRST HIDE THE CURRENT LIST
    $(this).hide();

    // THEN CONSTRUCT THE ORIGINAL LIST CLASS or ID
    var x_orig = "." + $(this).attr('class') + "_orig"; // CLASS USING "."
    // var x_orig = "#" + $(this).attr('class') + "_orig"; // or ID USING "#"

    // NOW SHOW ORIGINAL USING x_orig VARIABLE FROM ABOVE
    $(x_orig).show();

    console.log($(this));
}
```

Comment: New edit for you @w0rldart. Hope that helps. Can't really do more without seeing more HTML really.

Comment: I like your soultion, it's exactly what I was looking for but... I get an error `syntax error
[Break On This Error]  

var content = x_orig[0]->innerHtml;`

Comment: I've tried various things but this ain't working man... where did you tried it?

Comment: I tried a test case on jsBin mate. I can get a live test version on there or jsFiddle for you this evening if that's any good?

Comment: Ah ok here you go then. Edited.

Comment: check my response, I've manage to fix it... and btw, I've tried your update... still nothing (for me)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7053/discussion-between-steve-o-and-w0rldart)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what exactly do you, but let me try :) I made two lists, original and the one with 'modified' information:

```
<ul id='list'>
    <li class='box'>orig box1</li>
    <li class='box2'>fake box1</li>
    <li class='box'>orig box2</li>
    <li class='car'>orig car1</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul id='list2'>
    <li class='box'>mod box1</li>
    <li class='box2'>mod_fake box1</li>
    <li class='box'>mod box2</li>
    <li class='car'>mod car1</li>
</ul>
```

And applied the following code:

```
var list              =   $("ul#list");
var box_orig  = list.children('.box');
var car_orig  = list.children('.car');
var counts = {'box':0, 'car':0};

$('#list2 li').each(function() {
     var el = $(this).attr('class')+'_orig';
     if (typeof (window[el]) !== 'undefined') 
     { 
       $(this).html($(window[el][counts[$(this).attr('class')]]).html());    
       counts[$(this).attr('class')]++;
     }
 });
```

**Updated:**
If you are just trying to restore the original values of li in the list then this code might be much easier and simple

```
// save data after page load
$('#list li').each(function(){  
    if ($(this).hasClass('box') || $(this).hasClass('car')) $(this).data('original', $(this).html());
})

// when data was updated use this code
$('#list li').each(function(){  /
    if ($(this).hasClass('box') || $(this).hasClass('car')) $(this).html($(this).data('original'));
})
```

Comment: no counts @Cheery, just `.box`/`.car`, its just li.box contains data (another list) that needs to be replaced with box_orig

Comment: @w0rldart      box_orig contains the list, but in $('#list li') might be elements with another classes. You didn't show an example, that is why I wrote the code based on your example. I would prefer, for example, to hide or copy the whole original list and then replace the whole modified with it.

Comment: I just need to know how can I match in jquery li.box with box_orig... and then just switch li.box content with box_orig...

Comment: @w0rldart      The thing is that in case of "so if $(this) is li.box, replace $(this) with box_orig" $(this) is one li element and box_orig is a set of the elements. How do you want to choose with which element from box_orig are you going to replace the current one?? Or do you have only one element in box_orig?

Comment: @w0rldart      please show html code too, because $('#list li').each( deals with one element at a time, not a set of elements, and you have to deal with index of the element as I showed in my code.

Comment: @w0rldart      you do not read me carefully. Again, car_orig is array of elements, $(this) is one element. Which element from car_orig should be taken to be shown instead of $(this)? Why won't you describe you problem from the beginning, may be you are trying to reinvent a bicycle? It looks like you have an original list, which updates somehow, right? And for the updated values you want to show the originals, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct Cheery but car_orig contains the SAME list as $(this)... both `console.log($(this))` and `console.log(car_orig)` contains the same thing, only in different order...

Comment: @w0rldart      but still, it contains the list and you have to choose which element from the list to take in order to replace the one from "each" statement. BTW, there is much easier solution without creation of the global variables - I'll write it in a few minutes.

Comment: it doesn't work but I've fixed it... check my response... DAMN

Answer (score -1):

This seems backwards; I don't know why you'd want to create something that enabled modification, then upon an event, replace that modification with original information. 
At any rate, here a few questions that would provide helpful information to people trying to give you a satisfactory answer:

1) Where is the "original list" coming from? Is it stagnant HTML, is it either an object or an array grabbed from a database?

2) If any, what server architecture are you using (e.g. PHP/MySQL)?

3) Do you have any HTML we can see?

I think you might want to do something like:

1) Have an initial list populated by results from a MySQL database.
2) Have a text input field for a Car and a text input field for a Box.
3) Have a user put text in those inputs, then click something, like a button or a form submit.
4) Replace specific items in the initial list with the information from the inputs.

If you answer the questions listed above and provide a little clearer picture of exactly what you're trying to accomplish, I'm sure you'll get back plenty of good, functioning answers.

Comment: @dyelawn... the original list is coming from here `var list              =   $("ul#list"); var box_orig    = list.children('.box');
`